# Intersection of two tubes is bound

Tags: real-analysis

Let $C_r(L)=\{ x\in \mathbb{R}^k :\|x-y\|<r,\ \text{for some } y\in L\}$ where $L$ is one dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^k$.

Prove that $C_{R_1}(L_1)\cap C_{R_2}(L_2)$  is bounded.

My approach to the solution:

[image]

After that I am unable to proceed. Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any linear map between finite dimensional spaces is continuous. Consider the map $(av_1+bv_2) \to (a,b)$ [I am dropping arrows to make the notations simple]. This means there is a finite constant $C$ such that $\sqrt {a^{2}+b^{2}} \leq C ||av_1+bv_2||$. Now we have $||\alpha_1v_1-\alpha_2v_2|| \leq ||\alpha_1v_1-x||+||\alpha_2v_2-x||<R_1+R_2$ Form this we get $|\alpha_1| \leq C(R_1+R_2)$. It follows that $||x||\leq ||\alpha_1 v_1|| +R_1 \leq  C(R_1+R_2)||v_1||+R_1$.

Comment: The result is obviously false if $L_1=L_2$. If this is not the case then $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent. I have used the fact implicitly in my answer.

Comment: Yes they are linear,y independent. Sorry that I forgot to mention.

Comment: Yes, indeed the map is only well defined if they are independent...